# Bluetooth LeScan didn't on target

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

My android studio has bluetooth permission in manifest,
and here is my code:

```
private BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 1000000; //10 seconds 搜尋頻率 1S:1000
private Handler mHandler;

private NotificationManager notificationManager;
Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //推播接收媒介
    mHandler = new Handler();
    bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    //檢查是否支援藍芽
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "硬體不支援", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    // 檢查手機是否開啟藍芽裝置
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "請開啟藍芽裝置", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } else {
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }
};
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    scanLeDevice(false);
}
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
                    //判斷是否有重新申請推播的必要
                    //BEACON 取其名稱

                notificationManager.cancelAll();//清理舊的通知資料
                prb=device.getName().toString();
                noti.addJavascriptInterface(new JsOperation(),"test1");
            }
            };
};
```

I has test the mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);,
the result is true, but can't step into  onLeScan ,
I'm pretty sure the BLE device has sign.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to android.permission.BLUETOOTH you also need  android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in the manifest. Make sure you use the permission API to prompt the user for BLUETOOTH permission.

Your code won't enter `mLeScanCallback.onLeScan()` until a device is discovered. Use [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en_US) to verify there are discoverable Bluetooth LE devices around you.

Comment: I has check my device recive the ble sign .
I'm using the BLE scanner.

Comment: Now i check the java develop environment the SDK has lose so many file . but i had re-install all SDK by SDK manager .

Comment: Now i can't find a way to solve this.
I think the problem is the sdk package has some unexpacted error there.